# How did this SE user get 100 reputation points?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, comments

I looked this user up who commented on my post here on Law.SE and he has no history but does have 101 reputation. How is this possible?

https://law.stackexchange.com/users/426/matthew-read

[Can women also go shirtless in public legally?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/33966/can-women-also-go-shirtless-in-public-legally)

Comment: You did this dozens of times yourself, hence the majority of your accounts sit on 101 (or 103 by making one approved edit, or 107 by asking questions with combined score +2/-2, or 108 by asking questions with combined score +1/0 and making one approved edit, etc.). You know perfectly well why this happens, and that Meta Stack Exchange is where this question belongs, and that it has been answered there already. -1 for feigned ignorance and a complete lack of positive effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known as the "[association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/241697)": any user who obtains 200 rep on any single Stack Exchange site will get 100 rep upon joining any other Stack Exchange site.

Comment: He has no other sites.

Comment: @Muze: He does, but they're "[hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267121/241697)".

Comment: I did not know you could hide your stats. Thanks